# What do hector_slam with /odom?

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, gmapping, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a question about hector_slam.
This link [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot) say "Use in place of gmapping". In this case, I edit my launch file how say the text: "param name="odom_frame" value="odom" . My question is, What do hector_slam with this topic (/odom)? In case that hector do something. Someone have a example tf.?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127836/what-do-hector_slam-with-/odom?/) by [alex.filgueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/11401/alex.filgueira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2014-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The odom frame is used for providing compatibility with [REP-105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) (and thus, gmapping). Currently, odometry information is otherwise ignored internally by hector_mapping, as in the original application it´s use actually lead to degradation of performance (due to severe slippage of robot platforms).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alex.filgueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/11401/alex.filgueira/) on 2014-02-10**:
OK, thanks.